# Label Prints multiple times

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a list and I only want to print the label once. Right now, it prints for each variable.

```
if (isset($vocabularies));
$vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
if ($vocabularies) {
  foreach($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
    if ($vocabulary->vid == 5) {
      $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vocabulary->vid);
      if ($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
          print '<div class="vocab">Event Type: <br/><p>' .$term->name;  '</p></div>';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vocabulary->vid); 
 if ($terms) {
   print 'Event Type: ';
   foreach ($terms as $term) { 
     print $term->name;       
   }
 }
```